# any programming ways to save variable of program in linux?

Tags: linux, design-patterns, filesystems

I only have one machine and want to save some variable values like `a = 3` in linux. I can **resume** the last progress if **power-off** suddently happens.

I can only figure out two ways, one is to save in **files** and the other one is save to **DB**.

Are there any special ways to do like this ***without*** saving in files or db? any programming language is ok.

Comment: what? please explain.

Comment: @vol7ron I'm curious about any ways to saving some info what I want to keep in my program such as variable value.

Comment: You could flash your ROM.  Why are you avoiding a database or files?

Comment: @vol7ron I'm not avoiding. I'm just curios about any possible lol.

Comment: @vol7ron how to flash my ROM? any tutorial?

Comment: I don't see what there is to gain from this. A `database` is in the name.. a system based around data.  Yes, you could probably access sectors of the physical drive and develop your own compression and decompression algorithm to place bits and bytes on the hardware so that the system doesn't recognize it nor considers it a "file", but that collection of bits and bytes to be re-accumulated to yielding you information is essentially what a file is.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some confusion. Do you want to save the state of your program? If so then use text editor which saves your progress even if you don't save it using ctrl+s, like sublime or gedit. Otherwise please elaborate more on what you want.

Comment: I want to save some important variable in my program

Comment: you could use hashmap to store them mostly works the same way like DB. Key pair value, wherein key would be variable name and value would be the value

Comment: @Adi how are you going to store them if its not in a database nor a file?

Comment: @Adi That's my question, I'm curious about anyways to store infos to prevent from power-off

Comment: @code_worker as per my understanding. Even if you do find way, it won't be any different as to how it works for storing in a file or a DB. That is the reason why they are famous techniques. If you look at  it conceptually, they are similar using specific data structures.